# In python multiprocess, queue.put will block subprocess?

Tags: python

If put in q only 10 data, output looks below.

> if cnt>10: # kk's size is about 2000.
>   Begin CountChangePercentMT1 at 2016-06-16 15:19:30.706000: end-in 0 2016-06-16 15:19:33.291000 end-in 1 2016-06-16 15:19:34.990000 end-in 2 2016-06-16 15:19:36.921000 end 0 end 1 end 2 end-in 3 2016-06-16 15:19:38.748000 end 3 End CountChangePercentMT1 at 2016-06-16 15:20:06.665000:

If put in q 20 data,output likes below:

> if cnt>20: # kk's size is about 2000.
>   Begin CountChangePercentMT1 at 2016-06-16 15:35:36.661000: end-in 0 2016-06-16 15:35:39.330000 end-in 1 2016-06-16 15:35:40.954000 end-in 2 2016-06-16 15:35:42.828000 end 0 end 1 end 2 end-in 3 2016-06-16 15:35:44.669000

If put in q 50 data,output likes below:

> if cnt>50: # kk's size is about 2000.
>   Begin CountChangePercentMT1 at 2016-06-16 15:36:54.518000: end-in 0 2016-06-16 15:36:57.583000 end-in 1 2016-06-16 15:36:58.886000 end-in 2 2016-06-16 15:37:00.757000 end-in 3 2016-06-16 15:37:02.648000

The code is below:

```
def do_somthing(q_out,q,i,trueStartDate,trueEndDate,preStartDate,allExistTables,stock_gainian):
    #Init conn
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',db='tushare',user='root',passwd='',port=3306,charset='UTF8')
    #Init df_Cc
    df_Cc = pd.DataFrame()
    df_Cc['ticker'] = pd.Series(dtype=numpy.int64,index=df_Cc.index)
    df_Cc['secShortName'] = pd.Series(dtype=numpy.object,index=df_Cc.index)
    df_Cc['percent'] = pd.Series(dtype=numpy.float64,index=df_Cc.index)
    df_Cc['startPrice'] = pd.Series(dtype=numpy.float64,index=df_Cc.index)
    df_Cc['endPrice'] = pd.Series(dtype=numpy.float64,index=df_Cc.index)
    df_Cc['startDate'] = pd.Series(dtype=numpy.object,index=df_Cc.index)
    df_Cc['endDate'] = pd.Series(dtype=numpy.object,index=df_Cc.index)
    df_Cc['gainian'] = pd.Series(dtype=numpy.object,index=df_Cc.index)
    df_Cc['shizhi'] = pd.Series(dtype=numpy.float64,index=df_Cc.index)
    df_Cc['liutong'] = pd.Series(dtype=numpy.float64,index=df_Cc.index)
    while True:
        aa = q.get()
        if aa != None:
            ticker = aa[0]
            secShortName = aa[1]
            totalShares = aa[2]
            nonrestfloatA = aa[3]
            listDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(aa[4], "%Y-%m-%d")
            stock_mktequd_name = '%s%06d' % (init.g_mktequd,ticker)
            if (stock_mktequd_name in allExistTables) & (trueEndDate>=listDate>=trueStartDate)==False:
                str = 'select * from %s where tradeDate>=\'%s\' and tradeDate<=\'%s\' order by tradeDate' % (stock_mktequd_name,trueStartDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),trueEndDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
                df = pd.read_sql(str,conn)

                l = len(df_Cc)
                df_Cc.at[l,'ticker'] = ticker
                df_Cc.at[l,'secShortName'] = secShortName
                nn = df.shape[0]
                if nn>0:
                    #
                    startPrice = df.iloc[0]['preClosePrice']*GetQfq(ticker,preStartDate,conn)  # if nn>=n else df.iloc[0]['preClosePrice']*1
                    endPrice = df.iloc[nn-1]['closePrice']*df.iloc[nn-1]['accumAdjFactor']
                    percent = (endPrice-startPrice)/startPrice*100 # if startPrice!=0 else -100
                    df_Cc.at[l,'startDate'] = df.iloc[0]['tradeDate']
                    df_Cc.at[l,'endDate'] = df.iloc[nn-1]['tradeDate']
                    df_Cc.at[l,'percent'] = percent
                    df_Cc.at[l,'startPrice'] = startPrice
                    df_Cc.at[l,'endPrice'] = endPrice
                    df_gn = stock_gainian.query('ticker==%s' % ticker)
                    if df_gn.shape[0]==1:
                        df_Cc.at[l,'gainian'] = df_gn.iloc[0]['ref_gainian']
                    df_Cc.at[l,'shizhi'] = totalShares*startPrice/100000000
                    df_Cc.at[l,'liutong'] = nonrestfloatA*startPrice/100000000
        else:
            break

    q_out.put(df_Cc)
    conn.close()
    print 'end-in %s %s' % (i,datetime.datetime.now())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    kk = allStocksBasicInfo.set_index(['ticker','secShortName','totalShares','nonrestfloatA','listDate']).T.to_dict()
    cnt = 0
    for k in kk:
        q.put(k)
        cnt = cnt+1
        if cnt>10:   # kk's size is about 2000.
            break

    #q_out
    q_out = multiprocessing.Queue()
    #fork NUM
    NUM = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    t = [1]*NUM
    #
    for i in xrange(NUM):
        q.put(None)

    for i in xrange(NUM):
        t[i] = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_somthing, args=(q_out,q,i,trueStartDate,trueEndDate,preStartDate,init.g_data.allExistTables,init.g_data.stockGainian))
        t[i].start()
    for i in xrange(NUM):
        t[i].join()
        print('end %s' % i)
```